# MySQL INSERT statement not working when trying to introduce CSS into the database

Tags: css, mysql, phpmyadmin

[image]On my website I want to display lines of code from a database. 
When trying to introduce the CSS into the database I get a syntax error, although this statement works perfectly fine with HTML. Of course before inserting the HTML into the database I had to escape the `<` `>` tags. Do I also have to escape characters in the CSS?

```
INSERT INTO table (foreignk,language,content)
VALUES
(1,'CSS','cssplaceholder');
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to escape your HTML, you need to escape your *data*. That means any and all values. Remember to escape for the context you're writing to. For SQL that means the escaping appropriate for your SQL dialect (e.g. MySQL), but HTML, JSON and CSS, for example, are different.

The `<` character is meaningless to MySQL inside a string. Don't escape it. Keep your values as "raw" as possible. The idea is to escape them only for the context in which they're displayed, and to do that *when* they're displayed, not before.

If you HTML-escape your data, you'll have to unescape it when using it in an non-HTML context and then it gets ugly. This is why you often get emails with subjects containing the actual text `&amp;` which is a sign someone's got it very wrong.

If you're doing this programmatically look at using *prepared statements with placeholder values*.

Comment: thanks for the tip, but what should I do in order to insert CSS into the database without getting an error?

Comment: @Bogdan What error are you getting? If you're doing this from a programming language, use its prepared statement mechanism to provide parameters to the query.

Comment: When speaking to errors, please help us out by including the exact error text, copy-pasted, into your question or a comment. MySQL usually gives extremely specific feedback on the nature of the problem, but interpreting that can be tricky. If you can give the error, and the query that generated it, we should be able to figure it out.

Comment: That's a classic escaping bug, you're using `'` to delimit your SQL value and you're also using `'` *within* your value. This results on conflict unless it's properly escaped. Are you composing this SQL manually or programatically? Read up on [MySQL string literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html) if manually as you'll need to know how those values need to be encoded.